# Typescript generates definition file with import which cause error

Tags: typescript, rxjs

There are times when typescript generates the definition file with the following code, which causes a compile error:

```
// test.ts
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

class Test {
  get property() {
    return new Subject().asObservable();
  }
}

// test.d.ts
class Test {
  property: import("rxjs").Observable<any>;
}
```

Why is that happen and how can I catch these types of errors?

Comment: `import("rxjs").Observable<any>` is not invalid .. it references the type in another module.. what issue are you having with this ?

Comment: I will add the original code, sec.

Comment: typescript adding this import for me and it's broking the app unless I explicit add import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

Comment: Is "borking" a term of art I am not aware of ? :P What specific error is the `.d.ts` file causing. I can use this definition just fine as long as I have the types for `rxjs` installed and I am using a version of ts that supports the `import('...')` syntax.

Comment: When consuming the library, I'm getting type errors like error TS1005: ')' expected and error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir broking => breaking

Comment: What version of ts is the client app using? Is it using babel or tsc?

Comment: typescript 2.8 (not babel), tsc with webpack

Comment: And there is the problem `import` types were added in 2.9 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap#29-may-2018. The library is compiled with a newer version of ts.

Comment: Oh, I see, do you want to add an answer?

Comment: Added the answer, 10x :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import("rxjs").Observable<any>;` is valid syntax, if you are building on `2.9` or above. Problems with this syntax usually occur if you have a definition generated by a newer version of typescript (which uses the `import` type syntax) and try to consume it in an older version.

As we discussed in the comments this was indeed the problem you were experiencing. The solution is to use the same version of TS in the library as in the app.